# Input field doesn't appear after changing the selection field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Once the user selects 'Cancelled' in the drop-down menu, the input field should appear to the user, so that the user can enter their reason for cancellation.

But it's not working.

By default, the input field is disabled, and doesn't appear to the user.

I tried to use `onselect` but to no avail.

HTML

```
<div>
    <select placeholder="Status?" onselect="closeReasonAction" name="changeStatus" id="changeStatus" disabled>
        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
        <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
    </select>
    <input name="closeReason" type="RRField" id="closeReason" style="margin:4px; padding:2px;">
</div>
```

```
if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value != "Cancelled") {

  document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = true;
}
else if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value == "Cancelled") {
  document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = false;
}
```

once the user clicks on cancelled the input field disabled here should just be abled and appear for the user to enter

Comment: Why does the else branch exactly invert the condition? What do you expect the value would be in the else branch when you tested it in the original if first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the `onchange` function what happens when you change the select. Modify the `onselect` function to `onchange` function and add `opacity:0` into input style and make it `disabled` initially.

```js
function closeReasonAction() {
            if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value != "Cancelled") {
                document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 0;
                document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = true;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value == "Cancelled") {
                document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 1;
                document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = false;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <select placeholder="Status?" onchange="closeReasonAction()" name="changeStatus" id="changeStatus" >
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
            <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
        </select>
        <input name="closeReason" type="RRField" id="closeReason" style="margin:4px; padding:2px; opacity:0" disabled />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed your onchange function.

```js
function func(){
  if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value != "Cancelled")
  {
    document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = true;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value == "Cancelled") {
    document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = false;
  }
}
func()
```

```html
<div>

  <select placeholder="Status?" onselect="closeReasonAction" name="changeStatus" id="changeStatus" onchange="func()">
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
    <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
  </select>
  <input name="closeReason" type="RRField" id="closeReason" style="margin:4px; padding:2px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You have to remove `disabled` from the `select` element, and place `disabled` on the `closeReason` element, otherwise users will not be able to interact with this element.

- You need to add `opacity: 0` to the `closeReason` element, otherwise it will be visible when the page loads.

- You need to change `onselect` to `onchange`. [`onselect` can only be used for `<input type='text'>` and `<textarea>` in forms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event)

- You need to add `()` to the end of `onchange=closeReasonAction` so that it becomes `onchange=closeReasonAction()` since you are trying to call a function on its `change` event.

- You actually need to wrap your JS code in a function called `closeReasonAction`, otherwise you're trying to call a non-existent function.

## Example

```js
function closeReasonAction(){
  if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value != "Cancelled") {
    document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = true;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value == "Cancelled") {
    document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select placeholder="Status?" onchange="closeReasonAction()" name="changeStatus" id="changeStatus">
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
    <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
  </select>
  <input name="closeReason" type="RRField" id="closeReason" style="margin:4px; padding:2px; opacity: 0;" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The if condition should be inside a function and the function should be called on change event of the select box

```js
function closeReasonAction() {
  if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value != "Cancelled") {

    //document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById('changeStatus').value == "Cancelled") {
    document.getElementById("closeReason").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("closeReason").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

  <select placeholder="Status?" onchange="closeReasonAction()" name="changeStatus" id="changeStatus">
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
    <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
  </select>
  <input name="closeReason" type="RRField" id="closeReason" style="margin:4px; padding:2px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `onselect` with `onchange`:

```js
function closeReasonAction($el) {
  var $reason = document.getElementById("closeReason");
  if ($el.value != "Cancelled") {
    $reason.disabled = true;
  } else if ($el.value == "Cancelled") {
    $reason.style.opacity = 1;
    $reason.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

  <select placeholder="Status?" onchange="closeReasonAction(this)" name="changeStatus" id="changeStatus">
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
    <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
  </select>
  <input name="closeReason" type="RRField" id="closeReason" style="margin:4px; padding:2px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onchange function, rather than onclick on each individual option.

Use a value attribute on each option to store the data, and use an instance of this to assign the change (or event.target)

You have no ID on your text field

You're missing the end quote for your onclick function

```
<select name="" onchange="myFunction(event)">
<option disabled selected>Choose Database Type</option>
<option value="Green">green</option>
<option value="Red">red</option>
<option value="Orange">orange</option>
<option value="Black">black</option>
</select>
And the function:
function myFunction(e) {
document.getElementById("myText").value = e.target.value
}
```